# Instalar plugins de git para Jenkins manualmente

Tags: git, plugin, jenkins

Quiero descargar git para Jenkins, ya que no posee internet la computadora donde voy a realizarlo, descargo manualmente de las siguiente forma:

Voy a la pagina https://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/

Y descargo el archivo .hpi que necesito. Sin embargo cuando lo intento instalar manualmente me piden en Jenkins: Manage Jenkins → Manage Plugins → Advanced.

Subo el archivo .hpi y me aparece alerta que necesita una dependencia, con lo cual procedo a descargarla de la misma forma luego me pide nuevamente otra.

Existe alguna lista de las dependencias y el orden correcto para instalar Git? o con cual archivo hdi podría hacerlo ? o quizá alguna forma mas sencilla de hacerlo.

Comment: Porque no instalas git para Jenkins directamente del gestor de plugins? Use el plugin del gestor hace poco tiempo y no tuve problema. Saludos

Comment: Es en un entorno empresarial (Un banco) y se encuentran bloqueadas todas la mayoría de conexiones, puertos, no puedo introduccir perifericos de entrada entonces no tengo posibilidad me gustaria saber el orden de las dependencias al menos de git ?

Comment: Perfecto, me fije en la implementación que tengo y tengo git server, git client  instalado a partir del plugin de git(version 3.12.1 uso)

Comment: Recuerda que para realizar despliegue a servidores, necesitarás privilegios para algunos shared folder. Por más que logres instalar el client de Git en un servidor x, deberás con tar con accesos de lectura y escritura en otros servers.